# make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/test_cpu.dir/all] Error 2 when running cmake

Tags: gcc, cmake, torch

l want to install a Fast parallel CTC library from https://github.com/SeanNaren/warp-ctc. But l stack at the following step described in the link (**Compilation part**).

if you have a non standard CUDA install export **CUDA_BIN_PATH=/path_to_cuda** so that CMake detects CUDA and to ensure **Torch** is detected, make sure **th** is in **$PATH**

1)How can l find path to cuda, l'm afraid of making a mistake in

```
  CUDA_BIN_PATH=/path_to_cuda
```

and

2) how to ensure that **th** is in the **$PATH**  ?

because without that the code doesn't work.

here are the steps :

```
git clone https://github.com/baidu-research/warp-ctc.git
cd warp-ctc
mkdir build 
cd build 
cmake ../



-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.8.5
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.8.5
-- Check for working C compiler: /root/anaconda3/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /root/anaconda3/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /root/anaconda3/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /root/anaconda3/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Looking for pthread.h
-- Looking for pthread.h - found
-- Looking for pthread_create
-- Looking for pthread_create - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread - found
-- Found Threads: TRUE  
**CMake Warning at /usr/share/cmake-3.5/Modules/FindCUDA.cmake:771 (message):
  Expecting to find librt for libcudart_static, but didn't find it.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:20 (FIND_PACKAGE)**


-- Found CUDA: /usr/local/cuda (found suitable version "8.0", minimum required is "6.5") 
-- cuda found TRUE
-- Found Torch7 in /home/ahmed/torch/install
-- Torch found /home/ahmed/torch/install/share/cmake/torch
-- Building shared library with GPU support
-- Building Torch Bindings with GPU support
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/ahmed/warp-ctc/build
```

After running

```
make
```

l got the following error :

```
make
[ 10%] Building NVCC (Device) object CMakeFiles/warpctc.dir/src/warpctc_generated_reduce.cu.o
[ 20%] Building NVCC (Device) object CMakeFiles/warpctc.dir/src/warpctc_generated_ctc_entrypoint.cu.o
Scanning dependencies of target warpctc
[ 30%] Linking CXX shared library libwarpctc.so
[ 30%] Built target warpctc
Scanning dependencies of target test_cpu
[ 40%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/test_cpu.dir/tests/test_cpu.cpp.o
[ 50%] Linking CXX executable test_cpu
/home/ahmed/torch/install/lib/libTHC.so: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string()@GLIBCXX_3.4.21'
/home/ahmed/torch/install/lib/libTHC.so: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_append(char const*, unsigned long)@GLIBCXX_3.4.21'
/home/ahmed/torch/install/lib/libTH.so.0: undefined reference to `GOMP_parallel@GOMP_4.0'
/home/ahmed/torch/install/lib/libTHC.so: undefined reference to `std::random_device::_M_init(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)@GLIBCXX_3.4.21'
/home/ahmed/torch/install/lib/libTHC.so: undefined reference to `std::runtime_error::runtime_error(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)@GLIBCXX_3.4.21'
/home/ahmed/torch/install/lib/libTHC.so: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_replace(unsigned long, unsigned long, char const*, unsigned long)@GLIBCXX_3.4.21'
/home/ahmed/torch/install/lib/libTHC.so: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_create(unsigned long&, unsigned long)@GLIBCXX_3.4.21'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/test_cpu.dir/build.make:99: recipe for target 'test_cpu' failed
make[2]: *** [test_cpu] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/test_cpu.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/test_cpu.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:127: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

It seems to be a CMake problem that's completely unrelated to Torch and Pytorch.

From https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/16832
**Christian Pfeiffer** said "The errors you're observing mean that you're trying to link code built with GCC 5.1.0 or newer (that's what GLIBCXX_3.4.21 corresponds to) with a GCC 4.8.5 compiler, and thus the older libstdc++ shipping with that. More specifically, the cutorch binary you've got has not been built with the same GCC as you're trying to work with now. 
libstdc++ uses versioned symbols, with the @GLIBCXX_3.4.21 referring to the point when symbols were introduced. In your particular case, it's the C++ ABI change in GCC 5.1.0 that breaks the linking process. "

Comment: I don't see an error, I see a warning

Comment: @talonmies, but it should find libert  , isn't it ?  " Expecting to find librt for libcudart_static, but didn't find it."

Comment: @talonmies, please see my update

Comment: I don't believe the error you show has anything to do with that warning, and it certainly had nothing to do with CUDA

Comment: It looks to me like an ABI incompatibility error... Was the library `/home/ahmed/torch/install/lib/libTHC.so` compiled with the same compiler? I would guess that this is not the case, and is causing the error.

Comment: @oLen l think so. How to solve that ?

Comment: @vincent Compile both projects with the same compiler (easier), or make sure that the interface of libTHC.so links libstdc++ statically (more difficult)

Comment: @oLen, have you seen my updates ?

Comment: @talonmies, the problem seems to be related to gcc, isn't it ?